# Don't go into element tree in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have some XML that looks like

```
<page id="1">
  <subpages>
   <page id="2">
    <subpages>
      <page id="3">
    </subpages>
   </page>
   <page id="4"></page>
   <page id="5"></page>
  </subpages>
</page>
```

What I'm trying to do is pull out the top level `<page>` in the top `<subpages>` tag meaning I'm trying to pull out pages 2, 4, and 5, but not 3.

Right now I'm doing `//subpages[1]/page` but this gets all the pages inside of the first subpages tag. Is there a way to do this?

I'm able to do this in jQuery with

```
var c = $(data).find("subpages").first();
$(c).children("page").each(function() {});
```

If I can't get a proper xpath to work, is there a way to make Nokogiri behave like jQuery does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

```
/*/*/page
```

More explicitly:

```
/page/subpages/page
```

Also, you could've done this (but I try to avoid `//`):

```
(//subpages)[1]/page
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of your jQuery would be:

```
doc.at('subpages').xpath('page').each do |page|
    puts page.attr('id')
end
```

Result:

```
2
4
5
```